# двумерный массив javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Здравствуйте.
Есть одномерный массив объектов в которых хранится информация о баннерных изображениях на сайте. Например 4 элемента:

```
images = [
[0] => Object {src : path, size : '256x256'},
[1] => Object {src : path, size : '128x128'},
[2] => Object {src : path, size : '256x256'},
[3] => Object {src : path, size : '128x128'},
]
```

Мне нужно создать многомерный массив сгруппировав по ключу (size).

Что бы получилось:

```
result = [
[256x256] => [
   [0] => 'src_img1',
   [1] => 'src_img3'
]
[128x238] => [
   [0] => 'src_img2',
   [1] => 'src_img4'
]
]
```

Я делаю примерно вот так:

```
for (var i in images){
    result[images[i].size] = [];
    result[images[i].size][i] = images[i].src;
}
```

В таком случае в каждом из массивов ключи выглядят вот так:

```
result = [
    [256x256] => [
       [0] => 'src_img1',
       [1] => 'src_img3'
    ]
    [128x238] => [
       [2] => 'src_img2',  <-- неверная индексация
       [3] => 'src_img4'
    ]
    ]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно построить этот массив, что бы индексация в каждом одиночном массиве начиналась с нуля?

Comment: не указывайте индекс `[i]` в конце своей реализации и индексация будет по порядку

Comment: @Lexx918 если не указать индекс - массив перетрётся строкой. Здесь вам тут не php)

Comment: @Darth не буквально же) `.push()` конечно, если надо в конец списка добавлять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = {}
for (var i in images){
    // чтоб не затирать массив, создаем только если его нет
    if (! result[images[i].size]) result[images[i].size] = []
    result[images[i].size].push(images[i].src);
}
// { '256x256': [ '1', '3' ], '128x128': [ '2', '4' ] }
```

Comment: тут лучше сделать result объектом

Comment: согласен, затупил - дурное влияние php :)

Comment: @Grundy воообще этот подход не будет работать, потому что это же будет не тот результат, что ожидается в вопросе.

Comment: @Darth - https://eval.in/899697

Comment: @splash58 1) ТС хотел всё же массив, а не объект в результате 2) мой комментарий не в ваш огород)

Comment: @Darth Судя по тому, как он исходный массив написал, у него тоже дурное влияние php :)

Comment: @Darth, там по вопросу вообще непонятно что автор хотел, и судя по предоставленному результату, этот ответ ближе к ожидаемому результату

Comment: @Grundy в заголовке вопроса написано "двумерный массив", а сам вопрос звучит как "каким образом построить массив".. если тебе непонятно, может не стоит придумывать за автора?

Comment: @Darth, если автор не знает разницу между массивом и объектом, ему ее надо рассказать, а не ждать его следующий вопрос: почему у меня не работают функции массива

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно, Ватсон. Воспользуйтесь методом [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
for (var i in images){
    result[images[i].size] = [];
    result[images[i].size].push(images[i].src);
}
```

Comment: вообще этот подход не должен работать, потому что в этом случае для каждого размера будет только один элемент, даже если их было больше

Comment: @Grundy это к автору вопроса вопрос)

Comment: Это к автору ответа, потому что результат в ответе не тот, что ожидается в вопросе, хотя там то же самое - только номер ключа может быть другим

Comment: Да, все работает как нужно.  Пропустил очевидный вариант. Спасибо!